# Difference between Tibco MQ series Adapter and Tibco BW MQ plugin

Tags: adapter, ibm-mq, tibco, tibco-business-works

Could you please tell me the Difference between Tibco MQ series Adapter and Tibco BW MQ plugin.
Is there any advantages of using MQ adapters over MQ plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primary difference being the ease of use and deployment. Tibco MQ series Adapter works by using the MQ binding file and also it is invoked inside BW by using the adapter palette activities. MQ adapters are deployed as a separate entity as aar.

Where as ActiveMatrix MQ plugins enables developers  to directly interact with MQ destinations and there is no additional deployment of adapter service required.